# Implementing conditional fluent mapping according to db

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working with 2 different DB's in my app, a big(oracle) one for the online mode and a small(sqlce) one for offline mode.

The problem is with the mappings, the id generation strategy is not the same, I need a custom implementation on the sqlce(something like sequences but for the negative direction).

How can I achieve this ability, without my mapping contain IF's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good way to implement this http://kinnrot.blogspot.com/2011/02/per-db-conventions-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually setting it, can you define a convention? Then you would just have one if, which convention to load at session factory config time. Or maybe none if the convention can examine all the way into which dialect is being used (though I don't know if the fluent nhibernate objects available to conventions supports that).

Comment: I did something similar, will post it on my blog and add it here soon